# Binding to NotifyIcon Balloon

Tags: c#, xaml

On the xaml.cs Side it's quite easy to implement, On a button click I want a Custom `Fancyballoon` to display and to show the text, lasting for 4 seconds.  I want to make this into MVVM, How Do i bind to it? I used this to help [NotifyIcon](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon)

xaml.cs side

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FancyBalloon balloon = new FancyBalloon();
    balloon.BalloonText = "Hello World";
    MyNotifyIcon.ShowCustomBalloon(balloon, PopupAnimation.Slide, 4000);
}
```

XAML side:

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon x:Name="MyNotifyIcon"  />
```

Comment: I have to admit I'm not familiar with "fancyballoon" but it seems like you could just repurpose a custom looking tooltip template with ShowDuration set to your time and just use the tooltipservice for less hassle.

Comment: I really liked what WPF notifyicon had to offer :S